# numerically simulation of coupled PDEs using FD

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

im working on my thesis project about flexible manipulators,and i derived the equations, there are 4 coupled nonlinear PDEs that i need to simulate them numerically with MATLAB, MAple , ...
could you kindly help me with that?
i tried to use Finite Difference method but since they are coupled, i couldn't find a way to discretize them , please help me if you can.
thanks.
[image]

Comment: this might help: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hennessy/docs/petsc_tut.pdf